# Access to Model parameter in .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am moving all my javascript out of my views, and into separate .js files. But I am facing one issue.

Some javascript references a model parameter:

```
var data = @Html.Raw(Model.RunningTotalData)
```

@Html, and probably Model... isn't available in the js files.

One solution might be, in the `<div>` that the code is working with, create a data- type field? And populate it on the view, and then the js code somehow reads that data?

At the moment, the js is rendering a graph on a div, defined as:

```
<div id="allbalancediv" style="width: 100%;"></div>
```

Could I add a data-xxx there, and then refer to that data field in my js code? I'm not sure if that's the right way to go, or if there's a better option.

Comment: You already have the solution, output a script tag or use data attributes

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obviously can't render server side content into static javascript files. But you can still render a script tag that sets up data for your JS files.

```
// View
<script>var data = @Html.Raw(Model.RunningTotalData)</script>
<script src="/frontend.js"></script>
```

---

Or a data attribute that gives your JS code an id to fetch via AJAX from a JSON api would work too.